# How to better and smooth cracked heels and make them soft?

Tags: personal-care

How to better and smooth the cracked heels and make naturally softer my skin. Please tell me in detail, my heels are cracked and sometime more pain arises. When I use lotion/moisturizing cream then I feel pain and my heels are also looking bad. How can make them smooth?

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, you need to know why you feel pain when you apply lotion
>   on your skin. I recommend seeing a doctor to find out what is
>   happening that makes your skin painful and with cracks.

Once your doctor has given you the treatment and with your skin on a healthy state, you can try this homemade lotion I use to smooth skin and remove cracks.
Here's the recipe:

1. Ten crushed acetylsalicylic acid tablets
2. 3 tbsp of body moisturizer
3. 25mL of glycerin
4. 25mL of 20 Volume cream hydrogen peroxide

Mix it all together to create a lotion. Apply on your feet and cover them with socks. Keep it for eight hours and rinse with water. I like to sleep during this period. This is the only product that smoothes my heels! The lotion is very watery. You're not supposed to feel discomfort while using this lotion, so if you feel pain, you should rinse immediately.